# Greating a macro for 3 different actions in 1

Tags: excel, macros, vba

Sorry for my language, not native.

So here's may problem.

There is a workbook with about 30 sheets and data in it. I need to transform data to a certain format depending on the name of the sheet. I created a marco for each format that works well and is applied for all selected sheets. 
My idea is to create a macro calling one of three format-marcos upon checking the name of the sheet and format the data. Something like

```
If sheet.name = "111, 112, 113..." then 'if it fit the name do the format-1

call "Module_name_1"

Else if sheet.name = "222, 223, 224..." then 'if it fit the name do the format-2

    call "Module_name_2"

Else sheet.name = "333, 334, 335..." then 'if it fit the name do the format-3

    call "Module_name_3"
```

Thank you for your time anyway =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the select case statement to check the name.
The numbers here should be converted to string when comparing. This way, you can easily branch depending on your value.
If you need to change the limits, change 119, 229 and 339.

```
Select Case sheet.name
    Case 111 To 119
'if it falls into the region then do the format-1

        call "Module_name_1"

    Case 222 To 229
    'if it fit the name do the format-2

        call "Module_name_2"

    Case 333 To 339
    'if it fit the name do the format-3

         call "Module_name_3"

End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Examine the first two characters of all the sheet names:

```
Sub SID()
    Dim shn As String, sh As Worksheet
    Dim shn2 As String

    For Each sh In Sheets
        shn = sh.Name
        shn2 = Left(shn, 2)
        If shn2 = "11" Then Call Module_name_1
        If shn2 = "22" Then Call Module_name_2
        If shn2 = "33" Then Call Module_name_3
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the 'Call' but it looks nice and it's probably more intuitive.  If you really want to simplify things, try something like this.

Select Case sheet.name
    Case 111 To 119
  Module_name_1
    Case 222 To 229
  Module_name_2
    Case 333 To 339
  Module_name_3
End Select

Answer (score -1):

If the first character of the sheet name is the determining factor, perhaps this

```
Application.Run "Module_name_" & Left(shn, 1)
```